# File access control in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a web application which allows users to upload files and share them with other people across the internet.  Anyone who has access can download the files, but if the uploader doesn't specifically share the file with someone else, that person can't download the files.

Since the user permissions are controlled by rails, each time someone tries to download a file it sent to the user from a rails process.  This is a serious bottle neck - rails is needed for the file upload and permissions but it shouldn't be in the way taking up memory just for others to download files.

I would like to split the application on different servers for the frontend, database and file server.  If the user does to my site, they should have the ability to download the file directly from something like my-fileserver.domain.com/file/38183 instead of running it through rails.

What is the best option for this?  I would like to control file access at the database level, not the file system - but I don't want rails taking up all of the memory on my system for such a simple process.  Any ideas?

Edit:
One thing I may be able to do is load a list of files/permissions from mysql into a node.js app and give access rights to the file server as a true/false response based on what the file server sends in.  This still requires the file server to run a web server, however.

Comment: Any reason you aren't going through amazon S3 or rackspace for your file storage? They've got gems for rails/sinatra/etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be You could generator a rand url for file, and control by center system .

Comment: What does that even mean?  I guess I could have a sinatra app running on the file server to keep it lightweight and have it query a webservice running on the rails app to determine a user's rights to the file?